# How to display Toast Message if TextView is changed?

Tags: android, textview

How to display Toast Message, if TextView is changed in Android?

Steps:

1. I am changing TextView according to spinner selection. Consider that the selected item is `Hai`.
2. Now the textview is changed (textview is now `Hai`).
3. I have to display that value in Toast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use textChange listener

```
textMessage.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
         String s = s.toString();
         Toast.makeText(getActivity, s, 500).show();

    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
});
```

Comment: I tried,In afterTextChanged() function,I displayed Toast Message,but that is not working,Could you post any code?

Comment: let me just understand: you are using onItemSelected for the spinner, then you are getting the spinner text and inserting it into the textView? if so why you are not making a toast then?

Comment: After inserting in to textview(suppose textview is now 2013-9-9),I have to compare that textview value with current date(2014-2-4),then i have to display "Whether the date in textview is Before or after or equal to the current date)